# Inputenc error when unicode greek letters mapped to commands: Argument of \UTFviii@two@octets@combine has an extra }

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

I use `inputenc` to be able to write unicode in the source code and have it translated to LaTeX commands. For instance

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{221A}{\sqrt}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03C0}{\pi}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B2}{^2}
```

then `$√{π²}$` becomes `$\sqrt{\pi^2}$`. This is quite convenient and I use a keyboard layout with easy access to characters like α, β, →, ⇔, ∀, ⊂, ∨, ∩, √, ∞, ∑, etc.

But when I write, for instance,

```
$$\frac a b$$
$$\frac a σ$$
$$\frac σ b$$
```

The first line produces “a/b” as expected, but the second errors out with `Argument of \UTFviii@two@octets@combine has an extra }. $$\frac a �`. So does it in the third line, if the greek letter goes into the first argument: `Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence. $$\frac σ`. Funnily enough, it works okay if the command has only one argument, for instance `$\sqrt σ$`.

What is the reason for this, and can it be fixed?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03C3}{\sigma}

\begin{document}

$$a$$
$$σ$$
$$\frac a b$$
$$\frac a σ$$
$$\frac σ b$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: well a greek later consists in utf8 of more than one byte. The \frac grabs the first two as its arguments and so breaks the compilation of the utf8 char.  You will have to use braces \frac{σ}{b}.

Comment: But isn't there some way to expand the σ into \sigma first (perhaps some \expandafter trickery), such that \frac aσ becomes \frac a\sigma becomes \frac{a}{\sigma}?

Comment: the supported syntax for `\frac` is `\frac{a}{b}`  it happens that in some places the unsupported version with no braces works, but this is not one of them. Note this is not specific to frac, you would see the same with any latex command that takes an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported LaTeX syntax for all commands taking arguments is to use braces

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03C3}{\sigma}

\begin{document}

\[a\]
\[σ\]
\[\frac{a}{b}\]
\[\frac{a}{σ}\]
\[\frac{σ}{b}\]

\end{document}
```

works without error.

It is the case that if the argument is a single token the braces can sometimes be dropped but the Greek here is not a single token.

This only applies to classic 8-bit TeX in which each byte of the UTF-8 encoding is a separate token.

If you use a Unicode TeX such as lualatex or xelatex than the Greek alphabet works the same way as the Latin alphabet:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\[a\]
\[σ\]
\[\frac a b\]
\[\frac a σ\]
\[\frac σ b\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, that's a bummer. It's sometimes inconvenient to be forced to use the braces. I can't use xetex/luatex anyway. I guess one workaround could be to preprocess with a sed script or something, rather than use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`. If nobody else suggests a workaround (some black magic to force the σ->\sigma expansion to come first) I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @andrepd I've been using latex for 35 years or so and I'm pretty sure I have never felt the need to use `\frac` without bracing the arguments what are you doing that requires that ? (just asking)

Comment: Mostly just force of habit, haha x) It's no big deal (also it's not `\frac` actually, rather a command I defined for domain-specific notation that comes up a lot in my work — I just used `\frac` as an example).

Comment: Also, just a curiosity: how come `\sqrt σ` works fine? Wouldn't it also expect a single token and the same issue would apply?

Comment: @andrepd "accidental code paths" and low level features of the tex primitive `\radical` which does not take an argument in the sense of a TeX macro but rather (like all primitives) forces expansion of following tokens until it has the necessary non expandable token (which is the sigma here)